# Content goes off screen of my web page and overflow does not work

Tags: html, css

I am relatively new to html.

This is a simplified version of [my code](https://jsfiddle.net/sgqkkwb5/).

I want it so that I can scroll down to view the rest of the page, but I cannot do that. Any help would be very appreciated.

HTML:

```
<body>
  <div id="header">
  </div>
  <div id="nav">
  </div>
  <div id="ingredient">
  </div>
  <div id="direction">
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: All your content has been give position: fixed. Do you just want the header  and navigation to stay visible as the page is scrolled?

Comment: You're using position fixed on the Ingredients and Direction ID's. This forces the elements out of the flow (so overflow auto won't work in this case). And you're forcing the direction ID out of the viewport/flow.

I would recommend to revise your current page structure and avoid using positioned fixed. Normally, you rarely use fixed anyways.

Comment: Yea, I want the header and nav panel to stay visible while scrolling

Comment: Try this: https://jsfiddle.net/L5c5p1zk/. You only need to apply position: fixed to the header and nav panel in your case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that all your elements are set to `position: fixed` which sets them independent from the flow of the document. As such, your `<body>` has no height and you cannot scroll.

Remove your `position: fixed` and give your elements a static height instead (e.g in `px` instead of `%`).

I've done these adjustments here: https://jsfiddle.net/sgqkkwb5/2/ but you'd still need to change other layout properties to get the result you want.

---

**Off-topic (opinion):** 
Since you seem quite new to html and css, creating your own layout is good for learning purposes - however, if you are creating a public project of some sort I would suggest resorting to a grid system. Have a look at http://getbootstrap.com and specifically the [grid](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid) section.

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks a lot dude, really appreciate it!

Comment: Sure thing, bud

Answer (score 0):

Try this just changed position `fixed` to `absolute` https://jsfiddle.net/aavrug/u59bvt9p/1/

Answer (score 0):

Here is you solution [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tjbaezid/rohmkmt6/)

```css
#ingredient {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  left: 15%;
  position: relative;
  top: 70px;
  width: 60%;
}

#ingredient ul {
  padding: 1em;
  margin-left: 0;
  list-style: square;
  text-decoration: none;
  column-count: auto;
  list-style-position: inside;
  height: 40%;
}

h1 {
  padding-top: 1em;
  line-height: 0;
}

#direction {
  float: left;
  left: 15%;
  margin-top: 2%;
  position: relative;
  width: 85%;
}

#video {
  position: fixed;
  top: 19%;
  left: 60%;
}

ol {
  padding: 1em;
  margin-left: 0;
  text-decoration: none;
}


/*Body Styles*/

body {
  background-color: white;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
  overflow: auto;
}


/*Header Styles*/

#header {
  background-color: #f60000;
  border-bottom: thick solid black;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 25px;
  border-right: thick solid black;
  float: left;
  height: 15%;
  left: 0;
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 50%;
}


/*Navigation Styles*/

#nav {
  background-color: #f60000;
  border-bottom: thick solid black;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 25px;
  border-right: thick solid black;
  height: 26%;
  left: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 15%;
  width: 12%;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="header">
  </div>
  <div id="nav">
  </div>
  <div id="ingredient">
    <h1>Ingredients</h1>
    <ul>
      <li>2 tablespoons olive oil</li>
      <li>3 eggs, beaten</li>
      <li>1 tablespoon crumbled goat cheese, or to taste</li>
      <li>2 teaspoons chopped chives, divided, or to taste</li>
      <li>sea salt and ground black pepper to taste</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div id="direction">
    <h1>Directions</h1>
    <ol>
      <li>Heat olive oil in a large skillet over medium heat, swirling oil     
       to coat the skillet. Pour eggs into hot skillet; eggs will bubble and 
        firm immediately.</li>
      <li>Lift cooked edges of the omelet with a rubber spatula and tilt the  
          skillet so that the uncooked egg runs underneath the lifted edge. 
           Continue cooking, lifting edges and tilting the skillet, until   
           omelet is almost completely set, 1 to 2 minutes total
        cooking time; remove from heat. Spread out any runny egg evenly on 
        the top of the omelet with a rubber spatula</li>
        <li>
        Sprinkle goat cheese, 1 1/2 teaspoons chives, sea salt, and black 
        pepper over omelet. Gently lift one edge and fold 1/3 of the omelet 
           into the center over the cheese and chives. Fold the opposite 1/3 
          of the omelet into the center. Slide omelet to
        the edge of the skillet and flip, folded side down, onto a plate. 
         Top with remaining chives.   
        </li>
       </ol>
     </div>
   </body>
```